# CakePHP - Column aliases in SQL queries

Tags: sql, cakephp, model

Is there a good way to specify column aliases when performing find() operations on a model?

```
$this->User->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname) AS fullname',
        'email',
        'tel'
    )
);
```

At the moment, if I do it like this it returns the data like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => John Smith
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [email] => jsmith@example.com
            [tel] => 0123456789
        )

)
```

Is there a way to have it return the column aliases like normal columns?

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => John Smith
            [email] => jsmith@example.com
            [tel] => 0123456789
        )

)
```

Comment: This probably doesn't help you too much, but you could loop through the main array, merging as you go. That'll give you your desired output if you cannot get Cake to return them in one array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you're supposed to use [Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html).

Comment: But what could I do if I use CakePHP 1.2.10 and there is no option for upgrade?!

Comment: Then there is no good way. But there is always an option for upgrade. And even if its just to 1.3 (which already has virtual field support).

Answer (score 0):

For **cakephp 2.x** in query:

```
'CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname) AS User__fullname',
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries